# Equivalent boolean statements have different results

Tags: java

I am confused about how && operator is working

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cartModification.getStatusCode()) 
    && (cartModification.getStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase(UNFCommerceCartModificationStatus.Sell_Out)))
```

Above statement is coming as true

while

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cartModification.getStatusCode()) 
    && cartModification.getStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase(UNFCommerceCartModificationStatus.Sell_Out))
```

is evluaated as false.Only difference between the 2 statements are braces.

As an additional input i have checked it with debugger and

```
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cartModification.getStatusCode() =true
cartModification.getStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase(UNFCommerceCartModificationStatus.Sell_Out)=true
```

I just added extra parenthesis in the second part and it was evaluated as true, Data is same as i have pointed out in question.

Comment: There's no way the difference in result is caused only by adding an extra pair of parentheses. Something else must be causing this. Try to run your code in a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: not possible... just try if (true && true) and if (true && (true)) or any other combinations...

Comment: Those statements are equivalent, either this isn't the full statement or you are not using the exact same data.

Comment: @Jesper: i am agree and i saw with debugger, everything is coming as true and i was of impression , but it was evaluated as false

Comment: @jamp: i am agree but when i tested it it was not as per expectation, that is the reason i posted question as i am also confused

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : this is full statement a copy paste from the original code and data is also same, i have not done any editing before posting question

Comment: It's just not possible... data must have changed between the two executions... try to run it one ofter the other

Comment: @jamp: how can data be changed? i m getting `cartModification` object from the `Facade` and it is final and i can see no reason that value has been changed

Comment: Final classes can be mutable.

Comment: ok try: boolean a = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cartModification.getStatusCode(); boolean b = cartModification.getStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase(UNFCommerceCartModificationStatus.Sell_Out); print(a && b); print(a && (b))

Comment: Whatever the cause is, it's simply impossible that it's because of the extra pair of parentheses. Stop fixating on that, look for other possible causes.

Comment: Umesh, the case is, your code resolves to either the first or second statement in jamp's first comment. Boths cases resolves in `if(true)`. This means `at least one` of your conditions must have been `false` at the time of testing.

Comment: @Jesper: I am fully agree with you, but what confused me a lot is, i only added that extra parentheses and statement started to getting evaluated as true,anyways i am debugging it more deeply to see what is the actual cause.Thanks for input

Comment: If you can decompile your class file, then compare the bytecode generated and you should find out why it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the commentbox isn't really approriate for this one:

How about trying this in a single run.

```
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cartModification.getStatusCode()) 
    && cartModification.getStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase(UNFCommerceCartModificationStatus.Sell_Out))
    System.out.println("First try is true");

if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cartModification.getStatusCode()) 
    && (cartModification.getStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase(UNFCommerceCartModificationStatus.Sell_Out)))
    System.out.println("Second try is true");
```

No matter what, you should either get no or two lines (since both statements are the same).

**Note** it's possible that just one line is printed, this means that any call on `getStatusCode()` invokes a change on any value used in at least one of the conditions.

Comment: Agreed and I did the same test. Some other thread changed cartModification's state or UNFCommerceCartModificationStatus.Sell_Out.